# Where is the source code for sortArrayWith in kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin

I am reading this code and trying to figure out how sorWith uses a comparator object. The fuction is defined thus:

```
    public actual fun <T> Array<out T>.sortWith(comparator: Comparator<in T>): Unit {
        if (size > 1) sortArrayWith(this, 0, size, comparator)}
```

But I haven't been able to find the source code for `sortArrayWith` any where. I'd like to know how  it actually uses `comparator`

Here's the code mentioned above:

```
val products = arrayOf(Product("iPhone 8 Plus 64G", 850.00),
                        Product("iPhone 8 Plus 256G", 1100.00),
                        Product("Apple iPod touch 16GB", 246.00),
                        Product("Apple iPod Nano 16GB", 234.75),
                        Product("iPad Pro 9.7-inch 32 GB", 474.98),
                        Product("iPad Pro 9.7-inch 128G", 574.99),
                        Product("Apple 42mm Smart Watch", 284.93))
    
// public fun  Array.sortWith(comparator: Comparator): Unit
// -> Sorts the array in-place according to the order specified by the given [comparator].
products.sortWith(object: Comparator{
                            override fun compare(p1: Product, p2: Product): Int = when {
                                                p1.price > p2.price -> 1
                                                p1.price == p2.price -> 0
                                                else -> -1
                                            }
                  })
```

Comment: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/9fb0a75ab17e9d8cddd2c3d1802a1cdd83774dfa/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/collections/ArraySorting.kt#L363-L372

Comment: In the IDE, you can Ctrl+click functions to see their source.